# MySQL LIKE - partial match with up tp 2 different characters

Tags: mysql

Trying to look for partial matches:

> SELECT * FROM `watches_check` WHERE modelNumber LIKE
>   '*`URL`*'

sample data:

```
URL: http://www.domain.com/s/keywords=AK-1470GBST&id=123456
modelNumber: AK-1470GBST
```

I'd like to find if the modelNumber is in URL field but it returns 0 results all the time. 
Where did I go wrong?

Also, would it be possible to find partial matches, where there is say 1 or 2 characters different, for example AK-1470GBST vs AK/1470GBST ('/' instead of '-') will be considered a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT * FROM watches_check WHERE INSTR(URL, modelNumber) > 0
```

to check if your url contains the modelNumber. This will even work, if your modelNumber contains the wild cards for LIKE patterns : `%` and `_`.

It won't return partial matches. Have a look at Gordons answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is to get the SQL correct.  I think you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM watches_check
WHERE URL like concat('%', modelNumber, '%');
```

Note:  The single quotes were removed from "URL" and wildcards were added to the search.

The answer to your second question is a technique called Levenshtein distance (see the Wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)).  If you google "Levenshtein mysql" you will find various implementations of the algorithm.